# Having trouble with I2C protocol

Tags: c, i2c

I am working on a project with a couple of friends and I am trying to troubleshoot an issue that I am having when reading data from I2C pressure sensor.

The piece of code attached is the one responsible for the issue I am having. The pressure sensor that I am using has a digital count range from 81 to 16128. When reading the raw data from the sensor is changing by 256 (1 byte) so from 8017 to 8273 to 8529 instead of number by number like 8017 to 8018 etc. By consequence the function (value) does not change smoothly like expected. Any ideas of why it could be counting like that every time after 256 counts? It seems that its changing bite by bite (1000 0000) for some reason.

```c
void get_inputs(void)
{
        I2C_Master_Start();
        I2C_Master_Write(0x50);
        I2C_Master_Write(0x01);
        I2C_Master_RepeatedStart();
        I2C_Master_Write(0x51);
        rawHighByte = I2C_Master_Read(true);//Read the first byte and send an ACK
        rawLowByte = I2C_Master_Read(false); //shift the previously read value into the upper byte 
        I2C_Master_Stop();

        // Calculate the pressure from the received data
    
       uint16_t rawValue = ((uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8) | rawHighByte;
       
 
     // Convert to [-351, 351] range   
     float value = (((float)rawValue - 81.0f) * 702.0f / 16128.0f) - 351.0f;
     
     sprintf(pressure_str, "P: %f", value);

      
       lcd_clear();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: uint16_t rawValue = ((uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8) | rawHighByte; ?

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages.

Comment: In one place, you say 81..16128 should be mapped to -351..351. In another, you say 0..16383. And in your calculation you map 0..16127. Which one is it?!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using the following:

```c
uint16_t rawValue = ( ( (uint16_t)rawHighByte << 8 ) | rawLowByte ) & 0x3FFF;

float value = ( ( rawValue - 0x2000 ) / (float)0x4000 ) * 702.0;
```

This is all guesswork since you provided little information, and what little information you did provide is conflicting.

---

**Bug #1: Incorrect conversion formula**

Your inputs are expected to be should be in the range [0,0x3FFF] ([0,16383]).<sup>[1]</sup>

Theses are supposed to map onto outputs [-351,351].

They don't.

| Input | (((float)rawValue - 81.0f) * 702.0f / 16128.0f) - 351.0f |
| --- | --- |
| 0x0000 | -354.525665283203125 |
| 0x3FFF | 358.57366943359375 |

To map [0,0x3FFF] onto [-351.0,351.0)<sup>[2]</sup>, could use the following:

```c
float value = ( ( rawValue - 0x2000 ) / (float)0x4000 ) * 702.0;
```

| Input | ( ( rawValue - 0x2000 ) / (float)0x4000 ) * 702.0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0x0000 | -351 |
| 0x3FFF | 350.9571533203125 |

---

**Bug #2: High and low bytes are reversed**

You are using `rawLowByte` as the high byte, and `rawHighByte` as the low byte. So either you're using them backwards or the names are wrong.

The former explanation is more likely, since the behaviour you observe would directly result from using them backwards. A change of 1 in the low byte would result in a change of 256 in `rawValue` if you used the low byte as the high byte.

You used the following:

```c
uint16_t rawValue = ( (uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8 ) | rawHighByte;
```

| rawHighByte | rawLowByte | ( (uint16_t)rawLowByte << 8 ) | rawHighByte | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 0x0000 | -351 |
| 0x51 | 0x1F | 0x1F51 | -7.4981689453125 |
| 0x51 | 0x20 | 0x2051 | 3.4705810546875 |
| 0x51 | 0x21 | 0x2151 | 14.4393310546875 |
|  |  | 0x3FFF | 350.9571533203125 |

You probably should have used the following:

```c
uint16_t rawValue = ( (uint16_t)rawHighByte << 8 ) | rawLowByte;
```

| rawHighByte | rawLowByte | ( (uint16_t)rawHighByte << 8 ) | rawLowByte | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 0x0000 | -351 |
| 0x51 | 0x1F | 0x511F | 538.7969970703125 |
| 0x51 | 0x20 | 0x5120 | 538.83984375 |
| 0x51 | 0x21 | 0x5121 | 538.8826904296875 |
|  |  | 0x3FFF | 350.9571533203125 |

---

**Bug #3: Extra bits left in input**

But with the above fix, we get `rawValue` values that are outside of the expected [0,0x3FFF] range, so we get `value` values outside of the expected [-351.0,351.0) range.

Since the `rawValue` is expected exactly the entire range of the lower 14 bits, it's possible bit 14 and bit 15 are used for other purposes and should be filtered out. This can be achieved using the following:

```c
uint16_t rawValue = ( ( (uint16_t)rawHighByte << 8 ) | rawLowByte ) & 0x3FFF;
```

| rawHighByte | rawLowByte | ( ... ) & 0x3FFF | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 0x0000 | -351 |
| 0x51 | 0x1F | 0x111F | -163.2030029296875 |
| 0x51 | 0x20 | 0x1120 | -163.16015625 |
| 0x51 | 0x21 | 0x1121 | -163.1173095703125 |
|  |  | 0x3FFF | 350.9571533203125 |

---

1. In the question, you say the inputs are in the range [81,16128]. The formula in the question assumes the inputs are in the range [0,16127]. In the comments, you say the inputs are in the range [0,0x3FFF]. I used the last one you mentioned.
2. Getting both ends of the range to be inclusive is "tricky".

Comment: I tried that before but that gives me only a digital count that ranges from 20736 to 20799 which does not makes sense because the data sheet specifies that the digital count ranges from 0 to 16383. And if I use the way you suggested then the conversion to cmH2O that ranges from -351 to 351 would be inaccurate

Comment: Yes, I realized that my calculation was off after your suggestion! Also, I tried adding & 3FFF at the end but that changes the digital count to a range from 4352 to 4415.

Comment: Oh yes, after the formula but the thing is that behaving like the beginning. The numbers are changing like this: from 5.5714 to 16.7142 to 27.8571 all the way up to 351 like that

Comment: No, they don't. You still have the bytes swapped.

Comment: Moved info from comments into answer.